# Help with a basic regex to match tracker URLs

Tags: regex

I'm having a little trouble with regex. I need to match all URLS that end in 'announce' or 'announce.php'.

It doesn't have a anything complex so I wrote a very basic one that looks like this:

```
^http://.*?announce$
```

This only matches the URLs that end with `announce`. How can I modify it to select URLS that have a `.php` at the end too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess

```
^http://.*?announce(\.php)?$
```

might work

Answer (score 0):

`^http:\/\/.*?announce(\.php)?$`

(I escaped your forward slashes for you as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like:

^http://.*?announce(|.php)$